# Image uploading and manipulation using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, youtube

I'm trying to upload an image and have its thumbs immediately after uploading and get the link(path) when I click the thumbs. So I found this video in youtube that provided me exactly what I needed but I get these errors eventhough I was thorough in following the codes. Everyone in the comments seems to be not having any issues with the codes shown in the vid but me and my friends followed it individualy but we are having the same issues. I really wanted it to work.

Here is the video tutorial I was talking about:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RG0NAVPNvoo

And these are the errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: scandir(): Directory name cannot be empty

Filename: models/gallery_model.php

Line Number: 49

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array

Filename: models/gallery_model.php

Line Number: 50

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: models/gallery_model.php

Line Number: 52
```

Comment: When have errors is always good to post your code you have been working with so others can help . We can not help you just by errors being displayed.

Comment: Just looking at the errors, they seem pretty self explanatory. "Directory name cannot be empty"

Comment: @mustang83 codes are in the video tutorial.

Comment: @craig in the video, it worked yet mine didn't. I 202% sure that I didn't miss a thing. I checked it detail by detail for a thousand of times yet it's still not working.

Comment: Do not have time to watch video Tutorials.

Comment: You'll have to show us the gallery_model.